# Error C2280 in a simple piece of C++ code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, mfc

I'm trying to solve a "stupid" problem I got with Visual Studio Enterprise 2022.

I created a new MFC application from scratch, then I added this single line of code:

```
CFile testFile = CFile(_T("TEST STRING"), CFile::modeCreate);
```

When I try to build the solution, I get this error from the compiler:

```
error C2280: 'CFile::CFile(const CFile &)': attempting to reference a deleted function
```

I read lot of answers and also the [official MS Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-1/compiler-error-c2280?view=msvc-170) about this error but I still cannot figure how to solve.

Any hint?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CFile` objects can't be copied, but that is exactly what you are trying to do - you are creating a temporary `CFile` object and then copy-constructing your `testFile` from it. <sup>1</sup>

Use this instead to avoid the copy and just construct `testFile` directly:

```
CFile testFile(_T("TEST STRING"), CFile::Attribute::normal);
```

---

<sup>1</sup>: I would be very worried by the fact that the compiler is even complaining about this copy, instead of just optimizing the temporary away, as all modern C++ compilers are supposed to do.

This statement:

```
CFile testFile = CFile(_T("TEST STRING"), CFile::Attribute::normal);
```

Is effectively just syntax sugar for this (hence the `delete`'d copy constructor being called):

```
CFile testFile(CFile(_T("TEST STRING"), CFile::Attribute::normal));
```

Which modern compilers since C++17 onward are *supposed* to optimize to this:

```
CFile testFile(_T("TEST STRING"), CFile::Attribute::normal);
```

However, at least [according to MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version?view=msvc-170), Visual Studio defaults to C++14 by default.  So make sure you are compiling for a later C++ version instead.

Comment: This is not about a missed optimization. `T x = T();` is identical to `T x();`, as a language rule.

Comment: @IInspectable I agree, but that is apparently not happpening in the OP's case. That rule was added in C++17, but I think the OP is probably compiling for an earlier C++ version instead.

Comment: This isn't a rule that was introduced in C++17 (guaranteed copy elision applies to return values). This rule has, to my knowledge, existed since C++98.

Comment: Thank you a lot, it works! The compiler is VS Enterprise 2022!

Comment: @IInspectable Normalizing `T x = T(...);` to `T x(...);` was optional prior to C++17. Now it's mandatory. In many earlier compilers, `T x = T(...);` very much was commonly two separate operations - construct a temporary, and then copy-construct `x` with the temporary.

Comment: I remembered wrong. I *knew* there was something special about this transformation. That special thing wasn't that the transformation must happen, but rather that it is allowed to happen (it's special in that it was the only permissible optimization that can change **observable behavior**). You're also correct that C++17 changed things and made this optimization mandatory. @SalvatoreAnsani Out of curiosity, does the compiler also produce an error when building a release configuration?

Answer (score 3):

It seems you are compiling your program using a compiler that does not support C++ 17 or higher.

Before the C++ 17 Standard if the copy constructor is deleted then such a record

```
CFile testFile = CFile(_T("TEST STRING"), CFile::Attribute::normal);
```

is incorrect. The compiler will request that the copy constructor will be available.

Starting from C++ 17 even if the copy constructor is deleted nevertheless this record

```
CFile testFile = CFile(_T("TEST STRING"), CFile::Attribute::normal);
```

is correct.

Here is a demonstration program using gcc 12.2

```
int main() 
{
    struct A
    {
        A( const char *)
        {
        }
        A( const A & ) = delete;
    };

    A a = A( "Hello C++17!" );
}
```

If to compile the program setting the option `-std=c++14` then the compiler issues the error

```
<source>:207:33: error: use of deleted function 'main()::A::A(const main()::A&)'
  207 |         A a = A( "Hello C++17!" );
```

However if to use the option `-std=c++17` then the program compiles successfully.